# Hiding folders in XAP file

Tags: security, windows-phone-8, hidden, xap

As we know, we can see the contents of a `XAP` file by renaming it to .`zip` and opening it by any `zip` tool.

I would like to know if there is anyway to make the `files/folders` in the `XAP` file hidden?

i.e. If a person renames the `XAP` file to .`zip` and uncompresses the `zip` file to see the contents, that particular `file/folder` needs to stay "hidden." This is a requirement in my project.

Yes, the user may see the `file/folder` if he/she has selected "Show hidden folders, files, and drives" in Folder Options.

Answer (score 0):

1. Unzip the archive into a folder
2. Hide several of the files/folders using the methodology your OS provides
3. Zip the folder back into an archive
4. Rename back to XAP

Be aware that this is an extremely weak protection for your contents.